# Guess my naym before I fall

Tags: riddle, knowledge

I was a bird,
unheard-of and small
In love with the big fingerling,
I staked it all
Bit by the wolf
I lost it all
In pain and humiliation,
I began to loathe them all
In quiet, I began to
plan their fall.

Helped by falcon
I began to build my halls
Betrayed and sick,
worse fate did him befall
And so it began
All their downfall
Wolves, stags all
suffered their fall
Escape I did
before the lion's bawl

I returned to my home
without any care of it all
To save the pup
I made the fish fall
Complete it is not
the tale of my gall
Though I should tell you
I mean to have it all

> But given Richard's style
>  I might meet my end before nightfall

Comment: **naym** or **name**?

Comment: @Mithrandir naym is a hint

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are

> Petyr Baelish - Littlefinger

I was a bird,
unheard-of and small

> His symbol is a mockingbird

In love with the big fingerling,

> Catelyn Tully (Tully sigil = trout)

I staked it all
Bit by the wolf
I lost it all
In pain and humiliation,
I began to loathe them all
In quiet, I began to
plan their fall.

> Challenged Brandon Stark to a duel and lost

Helped by falcon
I began to build my halls
Betrayed and sick,
worse fate did him befall

> Jon Arryn (Arryn sigil = falcon) helped him (made him Master of Coin), but Petyr betrayed him (convinced Jons wife, Lysa, to poison him)

And so it began
All their downfall
Wolves, stags all
suffered their fall
Escape I did
before the lion's bawl

> Many characters died (Wolves=Starks, Stags=Baratheons, Lions=Lannisters), but Petyr escaped from Lannisters with Sansa Stark

I returned to my home
without any care of it all

> Returned to his home (The Fingers)

To save the pup
I made the fish fall

> To save Sansa, he pushed Lysa (born Tully -> fish) to her death

Complete it is not
the tale of my gall
Though I should tell you
I mean to have it all

> He is very ambitious and ruthless
>
>  I suppose even the title is a hint (naym -> Petyr)

edit: the hidden lines

> But given Richard's style
> I might meet my end before nightfall
>
>  George Raymond **Richard** Martin is known for "ending" a lot of characters so P.B. might end up dead before we expect it (Nightfall -> Long Night -> rise of the Others)

Comment: Awesome. What about the hidden lines

Comment: "before the lion's bawl" -> Cersei crying, "Complete it is not" -> We dont know what will happen to him in the upcoming seasons/novel.

Comment: @AnubhavTripathi Hm, I skipped the hidden lines. My guess: George Raymond **Richard** Martin is known for "ending" a lot of characters so P.B. might end up dead before we expect it (Nightfall -> Long Night -> rise of the Others?)

Comment: yes, I just meant that you should add it in the answer